# how to apply DTW on 2 dimensional feature vector matrix obtained from mfcc?

Tags: time-series, cluster-analysis, mfcc

I have two 2 dimensional feature vector obtained from MFCC. How can I apply Dynamic Time Warping(DTW) on it? Can I find the similarties between two vector in percentage?

Comment: well, you will first calculate a pointwise distance matrix using for example Euclidean Distance (also applicable to 2 dimensional points) and secondly you derive the accumulated distance matrix which results in the warping path and the total distance. Please read about dynamic time warping, implement it yourself or use any implementation in the internet and then come back with a specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

DTW has a cost associated with aligning time points.

You can essentially put in any distance function there, not only absolute or squared difference. In particular you *can* use $(a_1(t)-b_1(t'))^2+(a_2(t)-b_2(t'))^2$